# How to query postgreSQL database to check if a value exist ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hi everyone and thanks for the great job here.

I am building an application with ruby on rails and postgresql. I have sucessfuly connected to my database and I can query the database and visualise the response in the console with no problem.

My database contains all zip-codes and cities in the US( 45k + rows ). The next setp will be to get an input from the users , query the zip-code column to see if the zipcode exist and return (yes) if it does and (no) if does not.

Here is my code :

```
class PgGem_test
    @failmess = "Error : the postgreSQL gem has not been loaded correctly"
    begin
        @var_pg = require 'pg'
    rescue LoadError
        puts "#@var_pg | #@failmess"
    end
end

conn = PGconn.connect(:hostaddr=>"127.0.01", :port=>5432, :dbname=>"wp-app", :user=>"postgres", :password=>'Password2017')

res = conn.exec("select * from us_cities")

res.each { |row|
    id = res[0]['id']
    name = res[0]['name']
    zip_codes = res[0]['zip_codes']


    puts "id="+row['id']+ " | name="+row['name']+ " | zip code="+row['zip_codes']
}

conn.close
```

and it return something like that

```
id=45395 | name=West Hamlin | zip code=25506 25571
id=45396 | name=West Liberty | zip code=26003 26074
id=45397 | name=West Logan | zip code=25601
id=45398 | name=West Milford | zip code=26451
id=45399 | name=Weston | zip code=26452
id=45400 | name=Westover | zip code=26501
id=45401 | name=West Union | zip code=26456
id=45402 | name=Wheeling | zip code=26003
id=45403 | name=White Hall | zip code=26554
id=45404 | name=White Sulphur Springs | zip code=24925 24986
id=45405 | name=Whitesville | zip code=25209
id=45406 | name=Whitmer | zip code=26296
id=45407 | name=Wiley Ford | zip code=26753 26767
id=45408 | name=Williamson | zip code=25661
id=45409 | name=Williamstown | zip code=26187
id=45410 | name=Windsor Heights | zip code=26075
id=45411 | name=Winfield | zip code=25213
id=45412 | name=Wolf Summit | zip code=26422 26426
id=45413 | name=Womelsdorf (Coalton) | zip code=26257
```

I would like to get input from the user ( zipcode ) query the zipcode column-only to check if the zipcode exits and return a response.

I dont know where to start and would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your query would be,

```
conn = PGconn.connect(:hostaddr=>"127.0.01", :port=>5432, :dbname=>"wp-app", :user=>"postgres", :password=>'Password2017')
sql = "SELECT \"us_cities\".* FROM \"us_cities\" WHERE \"us_cities\".\"zip_codes\" = #{params[:zip_code]}"
res = conn.exec(sql)
p res.present?
conn.close
```

I just wonder, inspite on rails, you are not using `activerecord`, if you do, you simply do,

```
UsCity.where(zip_codes: params[:zip_code]).exists?
#=> true/false
```

Comment: My plan was to avoid using active records but im still debating with my colleagues the best way to go

Comment: I see, so the answer makes sense to you?

Comment: just replace your code from `conn =...` to `conn.close` with mine, you have to think about how you will pass the user input(params).

Comment: quick question though : Ive got this into terminal undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object (NameError). How to fix ?

Comment: exactly, that's what I meant by passing user input here, for the time being you can hard code your `zipcode` replacing `#{params[:zip_code]}`. I assume you might be having a form where user inputs the `zipcode` as params, that parameter needs to be passed here as argument

Comment: okay so #{params[:zip_code]} should be in fact user input ? sorry for the dummy qquestions. Still into the learning curve